# Create a complexe parse server or mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm using **[parse server](http://parseplatform.org) + mongodb** for back-end and I need help for creating an complexe query:

First here's a schema for my db : 
[image]

The `friends` model represent the friendship between two users. 
Each `user` has a `city`

What I'm trying to achieve is to create function that take an `userId` as input and return list of cities **Sorted by number of friends**.

Here's my code until now

```
function getCities(userId) {

  //This query allow to count number of friends in a given city 
  var innerQuery1 = new Parse.Query(Friends);
  innerQuery1. equalTo("user1", userId);

  var innerQuery2 = new Parse.Query(Friends);
  innerQuery2.equalTo("user2", userId);

  countFriendsQueryInCity = Parse.Query.or(innerQuery1, innerQuery2);
  countFriendsQueryInCity.equalTo("city", cityId)
  countFriendsQueryInCity.count({..})

  //This to get all cities
  var query = new Parse.Query(City);
  query.find({})

}
```

So the probleme is I can't figure a way way in parse or mongodb to join the two queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse doesn't support aggregation queries at this time.  Here's an example of how you can do this using the js sdk api.  In case you're curious, to make sure that this worked, in my checked out version of the parse-server repo, I created a spec file in the spec directory with all of the below in it then i focused on just the test (by putting an 'f' in front of 'describe').

```
/**
 * Return a sorted list of cities with count of friends in that city
 *
 * @param userId id of the user to build the list for
 * @returns an array of city, count pairs sorted descending
 */
const getCities = function getCities(userId) {
  const aggregation = {};
  const userPointer = new Parse.Object('Person').set('objectId', userId);
  return new Parse.Query('Friend')
    .equalTo('user1', userPointer)
    .include('user2.city')
    .each((friendship) => {
      const city = friendship.get('user2').get('city').get('name');
      if (aggregation[city]) {
        aggregation[city]++
      }
      else {
        aggregation[city] = 1;
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      const sortable = [];
      for (const city in aggregation) {
        sortable.push([city, aggregation[city]]);
      }
      return sortable.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]); // desc
    });
}


// the unit test for the function above....
fdescribe('play with aggregations', () => {
  it('should count friends by city and order desc', (done) => {

    // create cities
    const ny = new Parse.Object('City').set('name', 'ny');
    const sf = new Parse.Object('City').set('name', 'sf');

    // create some people to befriend
    const people = [
      new Parse.Object('Person').set('city', ny),
      new Parse.Object('Person').set('city', sf),
      new Parse.Object('Person').set('city', sf),
      new Parse.Object('Person').set('city', sf),
    ];

    // the object of these friendships
    const friendee = new Parse.Object('Person').set('city', sf);

    // make the friendships
    const friends = people.map(person =>
      new Parse.Object('Friend')
        .set('user1', friendee)
        .set('user2', person));

    // just saving the friends will save the friendee and cities too!
    Parse.Object.saveAll(friends)
      // all saved, now call our function
      .then(() => getCities(friendee.id))
      .then((result) => {
        const lastResult = result.pop();
        const firstResult = result.pop();
        expect(lastResult[0]).toBe('ny');
        expect(lastResult[1]).toBe(1);
        expect(firstResult[0]).toBe('sf');
        expect(firstResult[1]).toBe(3);
        done();
      })
      .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  So you're getting list of all user friends then loop the friends list and make the count of city, that it ?? 

Also what If the user have thousands of friends it will be too complicated because parse can't handle more then 1000 item per page ?

Comment: Parse.Query.each() doesn't have a limit.  It'll run through all of them.  The issue would be if there are hundreds of thousands or millions, it could timeout the connection.

the alternate would be to make a 'beforeSave' hook on the 'Friend' class and store the aggregation at save instead of looking it up when needed.  So you could have something like a FriendCityCount class that has userid, city, count as the columns.....

Comment: I thought on that but this add another table to handle, other functions ... It's wired why NoSql doesn't support join query

Comment: Mongo dpes support aggregations.   They just aren't exposed by parse yet.   One of the parse server contributors is keen to add them though.

Comment: The solution works but it show only the city where I've friends, city where I don't have friends are not listed) .

Comment: Also How to create pagination ?? to limit 40 result per page for example

Comment: The solution above is not compatible with paging.  If you need to support paging, then you should make an `afterSave` hook for `Friend` and `increment` a counter for each user/city pair in a `FriendCityCount` class.  And then make sure that there is an index on that collection to support looking up by friend id and sorting by count.  It may not be what you are used to from sql world, but it is reasonable, not a lot of code, and it will be very performant at any scale -- which is the real advantage of nosql: performance at scale.

Comment: So In the `FriendCityCount` I will have `numberOfCity*NumberOfUser` lines. and each line is represented like this `user, city and countOfUserFriendsInThatCity` .

Comment: Also do you have any leads about parse indexing ?

Comment: yeah, that's right. but the actual number of docs will be a lot less since most users wont have friends in every city ;)  your schema looks good too, but I would simply call the final field `count` since the name of the class is clear.  The index will be: `db.FriendCityCount.createIndex( { "_p_user": 1, "count": -1 } )` so you can look up all records by user ordered by count descending.  For fast incrementing of count, you'll want an index on `{"_p_user": 1, "_p_city": 1}` and city